# Pass second output of procedure to SSIS OLEDB Command

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, ssis-2012, msbi

I have a situation where I am using a dataflow task where I am populating data (Call SQL command) from an OLEDB source and inserting it at the destination using vdestination.

In the OLEDB source, I am calling a stored procedure which is returning the following columns in the second output set:

```
SELECT 
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
```

Now I want to redirect this second output column to the OLEDB command transformation in the dataflow task where I am calling one stored procedure for error logging.

Here are the list of questions:

1. How do I get the second result set of the OLEDB source and redirect to the OLEDB command transformation?
2. How do I pass parameters to a stored procedure in the OLEDB command transformation?
3. I also want to redirect the error output for all rows where all remaining rows can be logged.

Comment: What about ScriptComponent or adding this information to each row. I know 2nd option is less than ideal...

Comment: I told not to use script task component. For second approach processing data is very huge so this will make whole process slower.

Comment: What about using native SSIS error handling and catching error output then? It seems like you are trying to program your own error handling on top of SSIS's - usually this is the easiest way to go. Otherwise perhaps SSIS is not the tool for your needs?

Comment: Yes I am trying to do custom error handling because SSIS error handling is limited and I need detailed information on every fail with SSIS. I am trying hard. Hope will find solution soon.

Comment: Did you look into information available in event handlers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this using some trick with condition split and temp tables in procedure.